# Android: check if wear app is installed on paired watch

Tags: android, wear-os

I have two android apps(mobile/watch), and I want to check on the mobile app if the wear app is installed on the watch or not.

Any thoughts?

I searched but no results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's described in [Detect your app on another device](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/standalone-apps#detecting-your-app), there is also a sample in [Github](https://github.com/android/wear-os-samples/tree/8f3a0d6e00afc91255a41f97613ab0a373e02561/WearVerifyRemoteApp).

In a nutshell, you should:

1. Add `res/values/wear.xml` file to your watch module, specifying your app's capability:

```xml
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:keep="@array/android_wear_capabilities">
    <string-array name="android_wear_capabilities">
        <item>your_custom_app_capability</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

2. On the phone app, add a listener to CapabilityClient:

```kotlin
        val capabilityClient = Wearable.getCapabilityClient(this)

        capabilityClient.addListener({ capabilityInfo -> {
            // the watch with the wear app that contains
            // your custom capability can be retrieved from:
            capabilityInfo.nodes
        } }, "your_custom_app_capability")
```